# How to create screen select option like Google Meet or Microsoft Teams (Web Version) in my own WebRTC application

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

In simple WebRTC using `getUserMedia` we get a popup in chrome to select 'Entire Screen' 'Chrome Tab and 'Application Window' but in case of Google Meet and Microsoft Teams they made the screen selection custom. How do I do that in my custom WebRTC web application.